# Ignore null values when serializing json in c# code generated by openapi-generator

Tags: c#, json, openapi-generator

I have generated C# code for an API which uses `nullable` liberally (probably too much so). This API seems to use `nullable` in some places where it means "optional" (eg: a PATCH request body, where any field can be omitted and its state is not changed), but this generated code is sending these omitted properties with their value to set to `null` - which isn't the intended behaviour. To work around this I'd like to change the behaviour of the serializer to exclude all null-valued properties, which [this documentation from Microsoft seems to indicate is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties); sounds like `WhenWritingDefault` is what I'm after:

> `WhenWritingDefault` - The property is ignored on serialization if it's a reference type `null`, a nullable value type `null`, or a value type `default`.

The `openapi-generator` arguments I used to generate the client:

```
  --generator-name csharp \
  --library generichost \
  --additional-properties packageName=MailAPI \
  --additional-properties targetFramework=net6.0 \
  --additional-properties dateTimeFormat=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z' \
  --additional-properties nullableReferenceTypes=true \
  --additional-properties disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent=false \
  --additional-properties conditionalSerialization=true
```

In my C# program I initialize the client using HostBuilder and in there set the serialization option `DefaultIgnoreCondition` globally:

```cs
var host = Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureApi((context, di, options) =>
    {
        options.ConfigureJsonOptions(options: cjo => {
            cjo.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault;
        });

        options.AddApiHttpClients(builder: builder => builder
          .AddRetryPolicy(0)
          .AddTimeoutPolicy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
        );
    })
    .Build();
```

then instantiate individual API clients, eg:

```cs
var templatesApi = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITemplatesApi>();
```

When I call a PATCH endpoint to make a partial update (in this case a no-op, as a contrived example):

```cs
    var templateResp = await templatesApi.PatchTemplateByIdAsync(
        (Guid)template.Id, 
        new Option<UpdateTemplate>( new UpdateTemplate() { } )
    );
```

where the auto-generated `UpdateTemplate` class is defined like this:

```cs
    public partial class UpdateTemplate : IValidatableObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UpdateTemplate" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="author">Name of the author/creator of this object</param>
        /// <param name="data">data</param>
        /// <param name="description">A description of this object</param>
        /// <param name="name">Display name</param>
        [JsonConstructor]
        public UpdateTemplate(string? author = default, TemplateData? data = default, string? description = default, string? name = default)
        {
            Author = author;
            Data = data;
            Description = description;
            Name = name;
            OnCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the author/creator of this object
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>Name of the author/creator of this object</value>
        /// <example>John</example>
        [JsonPropertyName("author")]
        public string? Author { get; set; }

        // ...rest of the properties snipped for brevity
```

since the serializer has `DefaultIgnoreCondition` set to `WhenWritingDefault`, I would expect that the `UpdateTemplate` instance would serialize to empty because all of the properties are null and we have set/overridden none of them.

...but that's not the case, I get a JSON string where all the properties exist and are set to null. I modified the `PatchTemplateByIdAsync` method to print the serializer options and serialized JSON string immediately before actually sending the request

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"DefaultIgnoreCondition={_jsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition}");
Console.WriteLine(await httpRequestMessageLocalVar.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

> Earlier in the `PatchTemplateByIdAsync` method the Content is set like this:
>
> ```cs
> if (updateTemplate.IsSet)
>   httpRequestMessageLocalVar.Content = (updateTemplate.Value as object) is System.IO.Stream stream
>     ? httpRequestMessageLocalVar.Content = new StreamContent(stream)
>     : httpRequestMessageLocalVar.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(updateTemplate.Value, _jsonSerializerOptions));
> ```
>
> - `_jsonSerializerOptions` is injected via class constructor argument when the API class is initialized

and I see that the option is set as expected:

```
DefaultIgnoreCondition=WhenWritingDefault
{"author":null,"data":null,"description":null,"name":null}
```

...but had no effect.

I've tried a number of different approaches, including class-level and property-level annotations to set the serializer options, but the result is always the same - it doesn't exclude null properties when serializing.

I've been scratching my head all day over what I'm doing wrong here, but I can't spot it.

How can I make this `openapi-generator`-generated code not send null values in JSON request bodies?

Comment: Realizing I was using a v7 preview of openapi-generator via the Docker pull, I re-did the project using code generated by v6.6.0 (latest stable) generator `csharp-netcore` - ultimate outcome was the same.